# Reactjs Render method of childnode not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
render : function () {
        var childNode = "";
        if(this._shouldShow()) {
            childNode = React.createElement(window[this.state.data.type], {
                id : this.state.data.type + "-" + this.props.id,
                data : this.state.data,
                ref : this.state.level,
                setNextLabel : this._setNextLabel,
                setPreviousLabel : this._setPreviousLabel,
                disableMove : this._disableMove,
                enableMove : this._enableMove,
                loadWizard : this._loadWizard
            });
        }
        return (
            <div id={"box-" + this.state.id} className="modal wizard" role="dialog" tabIndex="-1">
                <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                className="close"
                                data-dismiss="modal"
                                aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                            <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            {(!this.state.status) ? "" : (
                                <div style={{padding: '10px',
                                    margin: '-15px',
                                    marginBottom: '15px',
                                    background: '#DC0000',
                                    color: '#FFF'}}>
                                    {this.state.statusMessage}
                                </div>
                            )}
                            {childNode} //this component is getting mounted but its render is not getting called 
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

---

There is no errors/exceptions in the JS console. Have no idea of why the render method is not even being called? Need a quick turn around for this, please. Added logs in componentDidMount method of the childnode and its being logged successfully. If I try to log something inside render method its not even getting logged.

Comment: Without a running example, it's hard to tell. Also, if your code doesn't run, don't make it a runnable snippet. Just indent the code and it will be highlighted

Comment: @JuanMendes sorry about that. Basically what I am trying to do is : render() { var childNode = React.createElement('myComponent', {props:prop1}); return(<div>{childNode}</div>); } which is not rendering the childNode, but its getting mounted

Comment: You should try to reproduce the problem here http://jsfiddle.net/metalshan/2HT8Z/ As it stands, I can't see what could be wrong.

Comment: What is the value of `window[this.state.data.type]`? And could you share the code of the particular `childNode` that your are trying to render?